# How to Detect Just the Ground Surface in Vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am following the Official Vuforia Documentation about Ground Detection 
Everything is going Will and i am able to Detect Planes and Flat surfaces, 
But i actually want to detect (just) one Plane which the (Ground) not the Other planes,

Is there a way to filter these surfaces and Detect just the Ground ?

Answer (score 1):

Check AR 8th wall, they have a feature for surface detection called "Ground only" which only searches for surfaces on the ground.
[Surface Controller](https://docs.8thwall.com/xr/#xrsurfacecontroller)

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, we are using vuforia for other purposes, so we are searching for an answer in Vuforia it self